# interacting with discord slash commands using requests python

Tags: python, python-requests, discord

I've automating message sending in discord with a simple script in python

```py
def sendMsg(token:str, channel:str, message:str):
    url = 'https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/' + channel + '/messages'
    data = {"content": message}
    header = {"authorization": token}
    r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=header)
    print(r.status_code)
```

but I want to automate also sending slash commands and there is were i get the error, i've tryed using the url `url = 'https://discord.com/api/v9/interactions'` maybe the error is in the url that need a channel id but looking with dev tools in the headers: `Request URL: https://discord.com/api/v9/interactions` the json im going to send gives some errors like true is undefined did you mean True same as null is undefined, i've just doble quoted that, do you know what is the error? the status code is always 400

full code:

```py
import requests
import json

token = 'thIsIsMySecreTt0k3n'
channelId = '1015655803383988314'

with open('data_json.json','r') as f:
    s = f.read()
    print(s)
    dta = s
    f.close()

def sendMsg(token:str, channel:str, message:str):
    url = 'https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/' + channel + '/messages'
    data = {"content": message}
    #data = dta
    header = {"authorization": token}

    r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=header)
    print(r.status_code)

def sendRank(token:str,channel:str):
    url = 'https://discord.com/api/v9/interactions'
    data = dta
    header = {"authorization": token}

    r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=header)
    print(r.status_code)

print(type(eval(dta)))

sendRank(token, channelId)
```

you may also need to see the data_json.json that try to send /rank to probot

```json
{"type":2,"application_id":"282859044593598464","guild_id":"1003270895185436803","channel_id":"1003270896359845998","session_id":"0eaab6fb154d359c5665ca016f1eec11","data":{"version":"971443831096635452","id":"971443830870126634","name":"rank","type":1,"options":[],"application_command":{"id":"971443830870126634","application_id":"282859044593598464","version":"971443831096635452","default_permission":"true","default_member_permissions":"null","type":1,"name":"rank","description":"View your rank card or someone else's in the server.","dm_permission":"true","options":[{"type":6,"name":"user","description":"User to get rank of."}]}}}
```

or the raw json without beeing modified

```json
{"type":2,"application_id":"282859044593598464","guild_id":"1003270895185436803","channel_id":"1015655803383988314","session_id":"0eaab6fb154d359c5665ca016f1eec11","data":{"version":"971443831096635452","id":"971443830870126634","name":"rank","type":1,"options":[],"application_command":{"id":"971443830870126634","application_id":"282859044593598464","version":"971443831096635452","default_permission":true,"default_member_permissions":null,"type":1,"name":"rank","description":"View your rank card or someone else's in the server.","dm_permission":true,"options":[{"type":6,"name":"user","description":"User to get rank of."}]},"attachments":[]},"nonce":"1015670347103469568"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change data=data to json=data, you should get a 204 response code which means it worked.
You also do not need all of that data, the only ones you need are below

```
{"type":2,"application_id":"","guild_id":"","channel_id":"","session_id":"","data":{"version":"","id":"","name":""}}
```

Session id does not have to be a vaild id, it just has to be a string that isn't empty.